# Can't resolve the problem Check if the DISPLAY variable is set<<<failed

Tags: oracle

I'm  trying to install Oracle 11g on Ubuntu 16.10.While doing so I'm getting the error "Check if the DISPLAY variable is set<<

[Here is the image of my terminal while working:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYIc7.png)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Installer likes to open a Graphical User Interface. If you are on a local Terminal you can type in:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

if You are logged in via ssh you need to close the ssh connection an reconnect with:

```
ssh -X ...
```

-X is generating the right "$DISPLAY" variable.

There is an Oracle Help Document regarding this error: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e47689/app_ts.htm#LADBI0123
chapter G.3 Remote Terminal Installation Error

Comment: I'm using my own laptop and I wrote export DISPLAY=:0 Then I ran again 
./runInstaller    but it's still not getting resolved

Comment: What happen if you run /usr/bin/xdpyinfo ?

Comment: It's a long output. Here is the output: http://pastebin.com/4KdSUyRz

Comment: okay. what happen if you try to run /usr/bin/xclock ?

Comment: A clock popped up in the window.

Comment: ps. I'm running those commands in a new terminal

Comment: by the way: Dont use 'export DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:0.0'. When you start you Terminal-Program there should be the right DISPLAY-Variable. Please check with "echo $DISPLAY" after starting a fresh Terminal-Session. Can you post the output of it here, please ?

Comment: Okay, if the xclock is coming up, then everything is fine with your $DISPLAY variable in this terminal session ! so this error with Oracle Universal Installer occurs in the same terminal session where xclock is working fine, right ?

Comment: yes,, and the output you asked is here file:///home/shamsad/Pictures/Screenshot%20from%202017-02-26%2021-46-35.png

Comment: sorry the link isn't working... the output is 0

Comment: I am glad to help you. Have fun with Oracle DB !